# How to hide bottom layout from Swipe-to-reveal RecyclerView menu item when user scrolls?

Tags: android, scroll, swipe

I am using [this class](https://github.com/MarkOSullivan94/SwipeRevealLayoutExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/markosullivan/swiperevealactionbuttons/SwipeRevealLayout.java) (there is a lot of code, so I won't post it here) to implement Swipe-to-reveal action, and when user swipes from right to left on any CardView item in RecyclerView, bottom layout is shown with some buttons. When user swipes from left to right, bottom layout is hidden:

[image]

Everything works great, but I want to achieve effect which allow users to automatically hide bottom layout with extra buttons when they scroll. There are methods named **open()** and **close()** in the class above, and I am trying to call them in **onDown()** method:

```
 mDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(mMainView, mRectMainClose.left, mRectMainClose.top);
```

but I'm getting this error:

- Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getLeft()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Found this [very awesome library named SwipeRevealLayout](https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout) from chthai64.

Maybe someone will find this useful, I did!